# Is it possible for a failed mod install to corrupt a world that is not opened?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know that if I either install a mod incorrectly or install a broken mod, it can corrupt my save data. However, is this corruption limited to any saves that I access, or can it occur in a world file that I don't even open with the mod installed?

I would like to know this because I tend to be a bit careless with backing up my saves, instead I just create a world I will use only for that mod, so it can't impact my other saves. Is this still putting my saves at risk, or are they safe as long as I don't actually play in them?

Comment: I'm going to guess no, however, you should still backup your saves, especially when playing with mods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing is impossible when you install a mod.

Mods are called mods because they literally modify (or augment) the binaries of Minecraft. They aren't plugins or addons or extensions, since Minecraft has no API for these sorts of things. Therefore, *any mod you install can do anything Minecraft has permission to*. This includes accessing the internet, any of your documents and saves, etc. This is why it's vitally important only to install mods you trust, just as you would any other program you obtain from the internet.

While **it's unlikely that an improperly installed mod would do anything to other worlds**, a broken (and poorly written) mod may attempt to modify your other saves (or any other files on your computer) and a malicious mod could destroy all of your saves and everything else on your computer.

Use caution, back up saves, and only install working mods from places you trust.

Comment: Woah, I had no idea that this could happen, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For normal, known, trusted mods that aren't actually viruses/trojans: no. There's nothing *you* can do during installation (failed or successful) that will cause world corruption in a save you don't load.

If you happen to be installing malicious code, then all bets are off of course, but even a poorly-coded mod would have a hard time *accidentally* touching a save directly without you loading it.